# gRPC set max send size

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm using grpc bidirectional streaming for request and response. Some of the response are oversized(larger than default max send size = 4MB). So I try to tune send size to 8MB by

```
server_builder.SetMaxSendMessageSize(8 * 1024 * 1024 /* 8MB */);
server_builder.AddChannelArgument<int>("grpc.max_metadata_size", 8 * 1024 * 1024 /* 8MB */);
```

But it doesn't work. Does someone know why this happens and how to tune the max send size?

Comment: For bidirectional streaming, you might need also to set server_builder.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(8 * 1024 * 1024);

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code? (allow the server side to receive and send 1GB data)

```
server_builder.SetMaxSendMessageSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
server_builder.SetMaxMessageSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
server_builder.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
```